# Spring Boot controller with custom status codes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In Spring Boot 1.3.5 (Java 8) I'd like my controller to return a custom status code and status msg.  By "Custom" I mean, a status code that is not in org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.

I know, I should stick with the standard codes (but I can't).

Currently my controller does a

```
 HttpServletResponse response

  .
  .

 response.setStatus(255)
```

I get the expected

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [255]
     at org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(HttpStatus.java:488)
     at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.getHttpStatusSeries(StatusResultMatchers.java:139)
```

Note, the operation may be successful, so in that case I want to return a custom 2xx code with a response object (i.e. sendError doesn't help).

Google says this may be available in springframework 4.3, but does anyone have thoughts for implementing now (with springframework 4.2.6)?

Comment: 4.3 make sense, could you use `sendError` instead?

Comment: Can you provide full stacktrace of your exception?

Comment: sendError wont for me because sometimes the code is for a successful operation and I need to return a response object (will update the question).

Comment: added relevant lines from stack trace

Comment: try to return a ResponseEntity

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue with your server but an issue with your test matchers. Please post more relevant details, a [mcve]. A sample controller and the test your run (minimally to reproduce this issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom http codes work on 4.2. This is the matcher in you junit that fails to assert the response code. Should work on your browser.